# Write avro files with LogicalType 'timestamp-millis' on date/timestamps in Java Beam pipeline

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have several pipelines writing avro files from streaming JSON records, but I'm having issues with importing them to BigQuery, because the logicalType for the date field is not defined in the avro schema.

Consider the following simple PoJo:

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class SampleClass {
    @AvroEncode(using=DateAsLongEncoding.class)
    private Date updateTime;

    public SampleClass() {
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Using this, the field is correctly saved to avro as a long. However, the LogicalType is not set in the schema, causing issues when importing to BigQuery when you want it to be a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` instead of a long.

I'd like to be able to annotate fields, just as with `@AvroEncode`. It would be nice to set `@LogicalType('timestamp-millis')`.

Has anyone ever accomplished something similar, or have any other easy method of specifying LogicalType for the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved using gson typeAdapters for deserializing incoming json like so:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Sample.class, new JsonDeserializer() {
   @Override
   public Sample deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
           JsonObject jObj = json.getAsJsonObject();
           return new Sample(
               jObj.get("timestamp").getAsString()
           );
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
           log.error("Sample parser failed" + e.toString());
           return null;
        }
    }
});
builder.create();
```

The Sample class, using java.time.Instant to create millis from ISO date string:

```
@DefaultCoder(SnappyCoder.class)
public class Sample implements Serializable {
    @AvroSchema("{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}")
    private long updateTime;

    public Sample(String timestamp) {
        this.updateTime = Instant.parse(timestamp).toEpochMilli();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try specifying `@AvroSchema` as in [this test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.23.0/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/AvroCoderTest.java#L100)
So your example would look like

```java
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class SampleClass {
    @AvroEncode(using=DateAsLongEncoding.class)
    @AvroSchema("{\"type\": \"long\", \"logicalType\": \"timestamp-millis\"}")
    private Date updateTime;

    public SampleClass() {
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Also have you considered using [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html) to write directly? It has [two write methods](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html), one writes out files and loads them, the other uses the streaming insert API.

Comment: I solved this by using gson typeadapters to deserialize json and creating objects through constructors, and then use @AvroSchema to provide correct schema for the AVRO file